# SMACH: How to stop an action currently run by the ActionServerWrapper?

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question follows [this old one](http://answers.ros.org/question/53764/how-to-kill-a-smach-state-machine-inside-an-actionserverwrapper/). As @bit-pirate, I have my SM running inside an action server wrapper. Following @jbohren explanatios, my SM receives the Ctrl+C properly and stops. So all is fine if my SM wrapper action server is not executing a goal. But when it is, its internal thread(s) keeps running and the SM node always escalates to SIGTERM, then SIGKILL on ROS shutdown. The SM is waiting for a SimpleActionState to complete, but as I'm amidst a ROS shutdown, that never happens

I have tried all tricks i can think about...

- request_preempt to the SM
- call _action_server.set_aborted
- send the  action server wrapper a goal that should stop intermediately
- ...

And all fails. So I must be missing an important point

[Here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/a1fe25e32c15821e1f6becb1db376781653bb328/thorp_smach/src/thorp_smach/object_manip_thorp.py#L193) is the code in question

Any clues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226624/smach:-how-to-stop-an-action-currently-run-by-the-actionserverwrapper?/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is not a problem of your statemachine but of the states that are not preempting correctly. I currently have a similar issue when executing MoveIt states but have not had the time to investigate deeper.

I found sending a new goal via axclient to the statemachine is a good way to debug this behaviour.

Hopefully i will soon have time to take a closer look at the problem, if i find a solution i'll let you know :)

---

edit:

i just took a quick look at an actionserver that moves another part of our robot (not MoveIt!) which reacts correctly when an abort is requested or a new goal is sent.

Below is a code snipped of the inside part execution. This corresponds to my current thoughts that if there is no frequent check whether a preempt or abort signal was sent the active goal execution will not be stopped...

```
while(((position - goal->finalPosition) >= 0.001 || (position - goal->finalPosition)  0)
            {
                //timeout--;
                // check that preempt has not been requested by the client
                if (as_LinearGuideMove.isPreemptRequested() || !ros::ok())
                {
                    ROS_INFO("%s: Preempted", action_name_LinearGuideMove.c_str());
                    // set the action state to preempted
                    as_LinearGuideMove.setPreempted();
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }
                ros::spinOnce();
                if(m_bLinearGuideActionAbort){
                    #ifndef __SIM__
                    m_CanCtrlPltf->setVelGearMpS(m_CanCtrlPltf->CANNODE_LINEARGUIDEMOTOR, 0);
                    #endif
                    ROS_INFO("%s: Aborted by operator", action_name_LinearGuideMove.c_str());
                    as_LinearGuideMove.setAborted();
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }
```

---

Originally posted by [ski11io](https://answers.ros.org/users/12261/ski11io/) with karma: 46 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0